How to set in QGIS for a loaded raster layer (settings > Style > minmax value settings > statistics extent > updated canvas) with Python Script?
I have a Raster layer loaded in a QGIS project and I want to change the the following setting by a python script:
Settings > Style > MinMax Value Settings > Statistics Extent
From Whole Raster To Updated Canvas
Anyone who can help?


You need to use the setLimits() and setExtent() methods of the QgsRasterMinMaxOrigin class:
raster_layer = iface.activeLayer()
raster_renderer = raster_layer.renderer()
min_max_origin = QgsRasterMinMaxOrigin()
min_max_origin.setLimits(QgsRasterMinMaxOrigin.MinMax)
min_max_origin.setExtent(QgsRasterMinMaxOrigin.UpdatedCanvas)
raster_renderer.setMinMaxOrigin(min_max_origin)
raster_layer.triggerRepaint()


great, it works... thanks
